# Filter between dates in QueryManager

Tags: 2010

I'm using a custom search implementation where I'm using the QueryManagers `UserQuery` property to filter my results, like so:

```
queryManager.UserQuery = "\"abcde\" Scope:\"Scope Name\"";
```

("abcde" is the term to search on in this case.)

But, I would like to only retrieve items created between specific dates, let's say only items created in November 2013.

Does anybody know how to form my user query to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

You can search on datetime property like this: `"Created:11/1/2013..11/31/2013"`

An `..` operator specifies a date range. On the other hand, you could also use a bit more difficult way `"Created>=11/1/2013 AND Created<=11/31/2013"` :)